# Objective-C send an alert when user performs action

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, email, message, send

I am writing an OS X application to prank a friend of mine at work. When he uses my app to place a fake order for coffee, and I need it to send a message to me letting me know that he placed an order. I looked at sending an email to myself stating he placed an order, but I didn't really want him to see it, and Apple doesn't like sending messages in the background. What would you suggest?

I am willing to share the app if anyone else likes to have fun at work :-)

Dev System: OS X 10.10 Xcode 6 Beta 3
Target System: OS X 10.9

Answer (score -1):

Is he running the iOS 8 beta? If not then there's no server infrastructure provided and everything that involves posting (via email or to social media) requires explicit user consent.

The easiest thing then? Probably [the Yo API](https://medium.com/@YoAppStatus/e7f2f0ec5c3c). It's zero-character communications so as you'd imagine there's not a lot to it. Sign up, get your API key, then issue a single URL request when he hits the button. You'll get the 'Yo'.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect that I am building an OS X application. I don't think he has an iPhone.

Comment: Oh, well the suggestion's the same. As of 10.10 and iOS 8 CloudKit will give you a server backend 'for free' (ie, if you pay your SDK dues) but until then you're pretty much looking for a suitably simple URL request to give you the indication. Or, I guess, with real computers at play, assuming no firewall issues you could do some more traditional TCP stuff and run a little server on your machine, having configured the app you give him with a suitably hard-coded IP?